# finding the eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let be a matrix $\textbf{A}$

$$
\textbf{A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} \\
0 & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ are given by

$$
\det(\textbf{A} - \lambda\mathbb{I}) = \det \begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} \\
0 & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix} = -\lambda(\lambda^2-(\frac{x\alpha}{2H})^2)=0
$$
hence we find:

$$\lambda_{1}=0 \quad \lambda_{2,3} = \pm \frac{x\alpha}{2H} 
$$

In order to find the eigenvectors, we have to find the solution to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 -\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\lambda & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} \\
 0 & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

for each of the three values of $\lambda$.

Thus we find the second eigenvalues $$\vec{e}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the third eigenvalue 
$$\vec{e}_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Here is my question**:

In the solution of the exercice I have, I'm given the first eigenvector as

$$\vec{e}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I would tend to say that the solution $\vec{e}_1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 0$ is given by

$$\vec{e}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the null vector is **never** an eigenvector. An eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a **non-null** vector $v$ such that $A.v=\lambda v$.

Comment: Thank you @Jose Carlos Santos. So $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}
$ cannot be an eigenvector. Now, if we compute $\lambda_1 = 0$ in $
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} \\
0 & \frac{x\alpha}{2H} & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$, how can we obtain the first eigenvector $\vec{e}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Solve the system $A.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. You'll see that one of the solutions is $x=1$ and $y=z=0$.